# Change the color of a region in Anylogic GIS

Tags: anylogic

I am currently carrying out a project to simulate the distribution of resources to different regions. Using Anylogic 8.3 together with GIS I was able to box the regions but I need the color of that region to change as the stock of resources goes down or up. How can I do it?

Currently nothing, I saw that I could use functions.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [help](https://anylogic.help/markup/gis-region.html#functions), you can call `setFillColor(Paint color)`, for example `myRegion.setFillColor(green)` whenever your stock goes up or down

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thanks for answering!!!
where can i write the function? i have a gis region as an agent and its based on the supply chain gis example from anylogic, i want to generate a color map that changes when stock reaches a number (i dont have the stock part yet)

What I try to recreate is the image that is in this report:
https://www.anylogic.com/resources/articles/logistics-simulation-and-optimization-for-managing-disaster-responses/

Comment: It depends on the specifics, tbh. Worst but global solution: use a cyclic event with an iof statement ("if value > X then change color to Y"...)